# Probability of getting k heads

Tags: probability

Here is the problem-

> A unbiased coin is tossed for $n$ times and find the probability of getting $k$ heads.

I know how to get the probability which is $\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

Comment: Stirling is probably your friend. But... you didn't mention the word "toss" or "flip"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$2^{- n H(f)} = \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$$
where $k = nf$.

So you essentially want to bound
$$\frac{\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}}{2^{n(H(f)-1)}/\sqrt{n}}
= \sqrt{n}\binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$$
from above and below by constants.

As suggested in the comments, Stirling's approximation is the easiest way to achieve this. [You can apply it to each term in $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Both_n_and_k_large) to bound $\binom{n}{k}$ from above and below. This yields

$$\sqrt{n}\binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k} = \Theta\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{k(n-k)}}\right)
= \Theta\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(1-f)}}\right) = \Theta(1).$$

Comment: I don't understand why the approximation gives the bounds.

Comment: @Www [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) implies $n! = \Theta(n^{n+1/2} e^{-n})$. Apply this to $n!$, $k!$, and $(n-k)!$ to bound $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: @Www In particular, note that the fact that $\Theta()$ is closed with respect to division (as it were) is essential here; if $f()\in\Theta(\mathcal{F}(n))$ and $g()\in\Theta(\mathcal{G}(n))$, then $f()/g()\in\Theta((\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{G})(n))$. This doesn't hold true for $O()$ (can you see why?) but the fact that you have bounds in both directions allows for this sort of manipulation.

Comment: I still don't get why the last big theta is the bound I need.

Comment: @Www In order to solve your original question, you need to show $\frac{\binom{n}{k} 2^{-n}}{2^{n(H(f) - 1)} / \sqrt{n}} = \Theta(1)$. However, I was unsuccessful and got $\Theta(1/n)$. I may have made a mistake somewhere, or maybe there is a typo.

Comment: I guess $$\frac{\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}}{2^{n(H(f)-1)}/\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$$ should be $$\frac{\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}}{2^{n(H(f)-1)}/\sqrt{n}}
= \sqrt{n}\binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Also, Where does your first equation come from? Thanks.

Comment: @Www Thanks, that was my mistake. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Www The first equation just comes from plugging in the definition of $H(f)$ into $2^{-nH(f)}$.

Comment: The log base is 2?

Comment: The log base must be 2 for Shannon entropy ?

Comment: @Www Yes ${}{}{}$